# How can I change icon of google maps marker in c# by some condition?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hi I want to change marker icon by some condition in c#.

Now I can change marker icon like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {

  var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');

 var mapOptions = {

 center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),

 zoom: 5,

 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var image = '/Images/station.png';

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title ,
        icon:image

    });


    (function (marker, data) {



        // Attaching a click event to the current marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            window.location = "Station.aspx?DI=" + data.DeviceID;
            icon: InitIcon
        });
    })(marker, data);
}
```

}

```
    public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=sample;User ID=sa;Password=1"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DeviceID=DeviceID,title=FirmName,lat=Lat,lng=Lng from Dealer where Lat>30", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }

    }
```

I set station.png icon to all markers.It is now working !

But I want change like that :  Stations with higher sales(station.png) and stations with lower sales (station_lower.png)

How can I do like that : Set station.png to marker for Station when "Select FirmName from Sales where SalesCount>1000 blaa blaa blaa " from database

Set station_lower.png to marker for Station when "Select FirmName from Sales where SalesCount< 500 blaa blaa blaa " from database

Set tank.png when "Select Name from Dealers where Device='Tank' " from database

Set bla bla bla.png when bla bla bla from database

Comment: Very good tip: If you create markers on a Google Map, store them in an array. Unless anything changed in the last year, you cannot access the exisitng markers again unless you keep them referenced in a variable. If you have a reference, you should be able to find the marker you want and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some flag

```
ConvertDataTabletoString function (boolean value to identify if salecount < 500 then set it to true).
```

Pass it in your data (`data.lat`, `data.lang`, `data.isSalesLess`) and then make if check in your javascript like,

```
var image = "";
if (isSalesLess == "true") {
    image = station_lower.png;
} else {
    image = station_higher.png;
}
```

Comment: @Mehmat, I do not know much about SQLserver and C# but if you can modify your DB query like, select DeviceID=d.DeviceID,title=d.FirmName,lat=d.Lat,lng=d.Lng, salesCount = s.salesCount 
from Dealer d, Sales s where d.Lat>30 and d.FirmName = s.FirmName

Then you will get salesCount in your result. This column can now be added into the rows and you can retrieve it in javascript.